# Unable to protect Cloud Run with cloud.run.invoker permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have deployed a simple Cloud Run service with Flask and I want to limit the access to logged users in GCP only.

I have set the `"Require authentication"` option and added the `cloud.run.invoker` permission to myself, but I can't access the webserver.

However, if I make a curl request with the Authorization Bearer in it, I can see the HTML of the page. What am I missing in order to see the page in the explorer? I know you could do this with a load balancer but I prefer not to.

My objective is to allow GCP logged users to access a page hosted in Cloud Run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work from the browser directly, you'll need to have an extension or something similar that will modify the HTTP request to add the header - much alike to what you're achieving with `curl`. [This extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en) may be useful for your use-case.

This is mentioned in GCP documentation right [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/developers#testing), just at the bottom of the page.

However this is not ideal, and if you want to authenticate any user coming in from GCP (i.e an internal user), refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users#internal) doc. You can make use of Identity Aware Proxy to create an internal app that any user logged in and given permissions through GCP is going to be able to access.

Comment: Yeah, I was willing to make it available to users inside my organization, but I'm afraid you are correct and if they aren't using an extension an inyecting the authorization to the header, they will not. Thanks!